# How to cite an edited book

Tags: semantics, reference-request, references

I want to cite some articles directly in *Semantics, Volume 2* by de Gruyter (2011). I wonder if each article in it is a journal or conference paper that can be cited directly. Otherwise, I should cite the entire book of *Semantics, Volume 2*, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to linguistics and is within the scope of [academia.se].

Comment: @Nardog, this post is not off-topic because it is related to linguistic bibliography. So it should be left open.

Comment: Although the general rule is to cite a specific chapter/article etc. in an edited volume (we're talking about an in-text citation I assume), no further detail can be offered in principle because **you didn't tell us what style you have to use** (Chicago-17, APA-7, MLA-8 etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Semantics, vol. 2* is authored by John Lyons, and published by Cambridge University press. That single-authored work would be cited as such. The item you are presumably referring to is *Semantics: An International Handbook of Natural Language Meaning*, edited by von Heusinger, Maienborn & Portner and published as *Handbooks of Linguistics and Communication Science* 33.2 published by de Gruyter, contains 36 articles each of which has a separate author and title. If you want to refer to the entire collection, you cite *Semantics: An International Handbook of Natural Language Meaning*, edited by von Heusinger, Maienborn & Portner etc. Otherwise you cite the specific article that you are referring to.

Comment: If I cite the specific article in it, should I also give the book name as Semantics, vol. 2?

Comment: No, because *Semantics, vol 2* is a different book. Actually, the citation would be *Semantics: An International Handbook of Natural Language Meaning*, vol 2 (for articles in vol 2). The first volume (same editors) is that title, vol 1.

Comment: Are articles in edited books generally published in other journals? Or are articles in edited books more like conference papers (i.e. with less review than journals)?

Comment: @user1006 In linguistics conference presentations are often republished in journals or edited books. The conference presentation should only be used if you can't get access elsewhere. Edited books are reviewed by the editors and possibly more. But whatever you use you must cite, other formats don't matter if you don't read them.

Comment: Those questions are pretty basic and you should probably read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edited_volume

Answer (score 2):

It's an edited volume, so each book chapter must be cited separately. Edited volumes are very common in linguistics and your style guide, supervisor, or librarian will be able to help you find the correct citation style.